# jQuery perform different action on second click?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a basic accordion in jQuery. When the user clicks the question, the hidden answer shows up. Currently, in order for the answer to disappear, the user has to click another question. I would like that to remain the same but I would also like for the answer to disappear if the same question is clicked again.

```js
var allPanels = jQuery('.faq-single .faq-answer-section').hide();
jQuery('.faq-question').click(function() {
  var nextAnswer = jQuery(this).next();
  jQuery(allPanels).not(nextAnswer).slideUp();
  nextAnswer.slideDown();
  jQuery(this).find('.faq-answer').show();
  return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="faq-single">
  <span class="faq-question"><span class="faq-question-icon"></span>Question?</span>
  <span style="display:none;" class="faq-answer-section"><span class="faq-answer-icon"></span><span class="faq-answer">FAQ answer</span></span>
</div>

<div class="faq-single">
  <span class="faq-question"><span class="faq-question-icon"></span>Question?</span>
  <span style="display:none;" class="faq-answer-section"><span class="faq-answer-icon"></span><span class="faq-answer">FAQ answer</span></span>
</div>

<div class="faq-single">
  <span class="faq-question"><span class="faq-question-icon"></span>Question?</span>
  <span style="display:none;" class="faq-answer-section"><span class="faq-answer-icon"></span><span class="faq-answer">FAQ answer</span></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Use `.toggle()` instead of `.show()`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but that didn't work.

Comment: `jQuery(this).find('.faq-answer')` doesn't match anything. `.faq-answer` is not a descendant of `.faq-question`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me:

```
var allPanels = jQuery('.faq-single .faq-answer-section').hide();
jQuery('.faq-question').click(function() {
  var nextAnswer = jQuery(this).next();
  if(jQuery(this).next().is(':visible')){
    jQuery(this).next().slideUp();
  }else{
    jQuery(allPanels).not(nextAnswer).slideUp();
    nextAnswer.slideDown();
  }
  return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var allPanels = jQuery('.faq-single .faq-answer-section').hide();
jQuery('.faq-question').click(function() {
  var nextAnswer = jQuery(this).next();
  jQuery(allPanels).not(nextAnswer).slideUp();
  if (nextAnswer.is(":visible")) { nextAnswer.hide(); } else { nextAnswer.slideDown(); } 
  return false;
});
```

Comment: Have you tried this? I don't think `answer` will contain anything.

Comment: @Barmar <span class="faq-answer">FAQ answer</span>

Comment: But it's not a descendant of `.faq-question`, so `$(this).find()` won't find it.

Answer (score 0):

This is working fine.

```js
var allPanels = $('.faq-single .faq-answer-section').hide();
$('.faq-single').click(function() {

 if($(this).children('.faq-answer-section').is(':visible')){
  
  $('.faq-single .faq-answer-section').hide();
 }else{
  $('.faq-single .faq-answer-section').hide();
  $(this).children('.faq-answer-section').show("slide");
 }

});
```